# initKeyboardEvent does not press key in input text

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I try to use `initKeyboardEvent()` function for press a key in a input, but it does nothing.
Do you know how to do this action?

```js
var event = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');  
    
    
 event.initKeyboardEvent('keydown', true, true, window, "a", null, null, null, "en-US");

 var input = document.querySelector("#theInput");

 input.click();
 input.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<input id="theInput" type="text"/>
```